# Enable button in Aura component 2 hours after case creation date

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an Aura component that contains a button and that is used on an Experience Cloud site on the Case details page. The buttons opens a flow in a model.

Everything is ok, but the ask is to only make this button enabled 2 hours after case creation time, so for the first 2 hours, this button should either be hidden, or disabled.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After obtaining the datetime stamp from the server, you can just check the difference in time:

```
<aura:attribute name="enableButton" default="{false}" />
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" />
<force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetFields="{!v.record}" recordUpdated="{!c.updateTimer}" fields="CreatedDate" />
```

...

```
({
  updateTimer: function (c, e, h) {
    let record = c.get("v.record");
    let now = new Date();
    let then = new Date(record.CreatedDate);
    let elapsed = now - then;
    setTimeout(
      $A.getCallback(() => c.set("v.enableButton", true), 7.2e6 - elapsed)
    );
  }
})
```

Where 7.2e6 represents 2 hours in milliseconds. We take the difference in milliseconds between then and now, and subtract that from 7.2e6 milliseconds. If the result is negative, the button is shown immediately, otherwise it will be enabled/shown as soon as the timer ends.

Comment: Does this work in Aura? Question was for Aura component.

Comment: @javanoob Oops. I may have been a bit too heavy on LWC recently. However, the conversion to Aura is simple enough. I've edited it as such. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: What's the need to use setTimeout? I used an if statement instead:
if (elapsed > 7200000) {
            component.set("v.enableButton", true)
}

Comment: @Walid This allows the button to appear at the appropriate time. For example, if the user loads the page at 1 hour, 59 minutes, the button won't appear if you just use an if statement, unless they reload the page. setTimeout makes it so it will appear exactly at two hours, even if they loaded the page early.

Comment: Oh, I got you! Thanks for your great explanation!